# HTML from Keynote not displaying on GitHub

Tags: git, github, keynote

Using the latest version of Keynote for OSX 10.9, I exported my slides as an `HTML` presentation.  I can easily view the presentation in a browser when I open the `index.html` file on my laptop.  To make the presentation available to others, I uploaded the `html` and `assets` files created by Keynote to a GitHub repository named `presy.github.io`.  However, when you visit the url for the presentation at http://presy.github.io/ it does not display in the browser and a `404` error occurs.  I have created basic websites on GitHub before with this approach and have not had any issues until now.  It seems like there is something not compatible with the Keynote `html` and GitHub.

Any suggestions on how to use GitHub to host a website for Keynote presentations exported as HTML?

The direct link to the repository for the `html`, `css`, and `javascript` files is at https://github.com/wigging/presy.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the [two types of GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages):

> ### User & Organization Pages
>
> **User & Organization Pages** live in a special repository dedicated to GitHub Pages files. You will need to name this repository with the account name, e.g. [atmos/atmos.github.io](https://github.com/atmos/atmos.github.io)
>
> - You must use the `username/username.github.io` naming scheme.
> - Content from the `master` branch will be used to build and publish your GitHub Pages site.

Note that these types of pages *only work when the name of the repository matches your GitHub user name*:

> **Tip:** You can only use your own account name for a User or Organization Page repository. A repository like `joe/bob.github.io` will not build a User Pages site.

So your Pages site isn't a User or Organization page.

The other kind of Pages site is a Project Page:

> ### Project Pages
>
> Unlike User and Organization Pages, **Project Pages** are kept in the same repository as their project. These GitHub Pages are similar to User and Organization Pages, with a few slight differences:
>
> - The `gh-pages` branch is used to build and publish Project Pages sites.
> - If no [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages) is used, the Project Pages sites are served under a subpath of the User Pages site: `username.github.io/projectname`
> - A [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages) on User and Organization Pages sites applies the same domain redirect to all Project Pages sites hosted under that account. Project Pages sites that use a custom domain are also available at `username.github.io/projectname`.
> - [Custom 404s](https://help.github.com/articles/custom-404-pages) will only work if a custom domain is used. Otherwise, the User Page 404 is used.

So you could set up a Project Page on `wigging.github.io/presy`, but to do so you'll need to rename your repository to simply `presy` and migrate your content from the `master` branch to a branch called `gh-pages`.

Comment: Ah, I was getting confused with the Organization Pages vs Project Pages. Previously, I had setup a page as an Organization Page so I was assuming that method worked for Project Pages. So, as you suggested, I put the HTML files for the presentation into a `gh-pages` branch and everything works fine now. Thanks for the help!